# Extract docker-compose.yml from an existing Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I have an existing stack in a Swarm that I'd like to add some templated variables to. The Swarm is currently managed by, but was not created in, Portainer. I no longer have access to the original YML that created the stack and many edits have been made to the services since it was used anyway.

Portainer easily lets me add and remove services, but it seems the ability to associate a service with a stack requires the original YML.

Is there an automated way to extract a YML file from an existing stack? If not, is there a way to associate a new service with an existing stack without using `docker stack deploy`?

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with using `com.docker.stack.namespace` in our staging environment. I believe this will just allow shortcut DNS resolution, so a service named `ecoeats_db` will resolve with just `db` as long as it is requested from another service in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker stack deploy` can easilly add new services to an existing stack namespace. Just don't use the `--prune` flag.

We use this a lot in our production and staging CD pipelines as we use stacks as environments, and so publish multiple microservices into a single stack - either by passing multiple --compose-file directives, or doing singular --compose-file stack deploys when a single service is implicated.

---

dockers dns resolution is even more interesting. Docker has no awareness of the stack namespace your services are deployed to - dns is resolved by the networks your service is attached to and the network aliases that have been implicitly and automatically assigned to your service.

network aliases can be explicitly controlled at the service level with no stacks at all with `docker service create --network name=my-network,alias=web1` and there is a similar alias syntax for the network section of services in compose files.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, thanks for the explanation.

Since I can just add new services using stack deploy, there's no need to maintain a running compose file with all the stack info I guess. Do you keep track of your updated mini compose files in git?

Comment: we do. gitlab is where we store the stack files and gitlab runners with access to the swarm(s) are used to deploy changes when the projects, or stack files, change.

Comment: @chris-beke Slightly off topic, but have you encountered the issue of docker swarm _not_ stopping old containers after updating the image of the service? After triggering the redeploy with portainer I often have to manually run `docker service update xyz` with no arguments to get Swarm to kill the old containers.

Comment: ive never had services left orphaned like that, except when they were in a desired-state=Stopped and they just kept going. The nodes they were on typically needed to be restarted.